# record timing of transitions in state_machine Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, state-machine

I have a Student model who can perform a series of actions. I create a state_machine for latest action.

```
state_machine :last_action, :initial => :get_invited do
     event :enroll do
      transition [:get_invited, :accept, :schedule] => :enroll
    end
end
```

I create a StudentObserver class, which extends ActiveRecord::Observer to record the time of the last action as follow:

```
  def after_transition(student, transition)
    student.last_action_at = Time.now
  end
```

I thought this function will record the timing of the last action (no matter what the last action is). Somehow it doesn't work, and I got empty field of last_action_at even if I transit successfully from one to another state.

What did I do incorrectly? How can I capture the timing of the latest transaction?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you saving the record after the transition?

Comment: I think state_machine automatically save the record. In any case, I can see my record's state updated after each transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A much simpler solution to this would be to create an on_transition hook and record the time there.

```
event :xyz do
  transitions :to => :state1, :from => :state0, :on_transition => :method_name
end

def method_name
  #set time here
end
```

Comment: Thanks Wahaj. Your suggestion would work. It would be great if I can write one statement for all events, and not repeat :on_transition to all events.